# two objects in the exact same place, two different positions in the transform tag at the Inspector

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm working on a 3d game in Unity, and as I wrote in the title, the are two objects that are in the same place but if I go to the Inspector, under the transform tag there are different coordinates.
It makes it harder to put the objects in a specific place.

I created a GameObject named "SchoolKidTotal". I also created a 3d collider named "SchoolKidCube" that is the son of "SchoolKidTotal". I placed the collider in about the same place as the gameobject. I expected that theird coordinates will be very close to each other but found out that they are actually far from each other.[image: coordinates of "SchoolKidTotal"][image: coordinates of "SchoolKidCube"]
I'm new at Unity and don't know much about it and I would appreciate any help, Thank you :)

Comment: Keep in mind that those are the local positions. If you have a hierarchy (that is, if an object is parented to another object), it may be that a parent in the hierarchy also has a position and orientation assigned, in which case the values you see are relative to those.